# Laravel Pagination: how to use custom pagination in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on laravel project and I want to use pagination on it,

For Project requirement I used Query like this:-

```
$result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ".$where." ORDER BY ".$sort." ".$orderBy);
```

And for pagination

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
```

and

```
Paginator::make($result, sizeof($result), 5);
```

But it show error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::make()
```

and When I used

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator;
```

It show error

```
Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator' not found
```

Please let me know how to resolve these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use Like This working for me

```
$accounts = User::select('user_id', 'name')->paginate(10)->toArray();

print_r($accounts);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = YourModel::where('condition', $value)->orderBy('columnName', 'DESC')->paginate(5);

return view('yourview', ['data', $result]);
```

In your view

```
@foreach($data as $result)
{{$result->tableColumnHere}}
@endforeach

//This will print the pagination links
{{$data->links()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't Paginator facade or make-method in that class.

- [Paginator Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator)
- [Paginator API](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html#method___construct)
- [Paginator Source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.php)

Instead trying to guess the methods and classes you can check the docs.

```
$paginated = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($result, sizeof($result), 5);
```

---

By the way all Laravel facades lives in the global namespace so you can import them without specifying the full namespace. Example

```
use Cache;
use Request;
```